# Can dew really make an eggshell fly?

Tags: rashi, science, beshalach, eggs, mon-manna

In פרשת בשלח 16:14, it says --

> The layer of dew went up, and behold, on the surface of the desert, a
>   fine, bare [substance] as fine as frost on the ground.

On that verse, Rashi says (translated from [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9877/jewish/Chapter-16.htm#v=14&showrashi=true))

> When the sun would shine, the dew upon the manna would rise toward
>   the sun, as it is natural for dew to rise toward the sun. [This is
>   similar to] **even if you fill an egg shell with dew, close up its
>   opening, and place it in the sun, it [the egg shell] will rise by
>   itself in the air**

Is this actually true scientifically? Has anyone ever tried or seen this?

Comment: Maybe with steam power?

Comment: @DoubleAA Sounds like a fun question....but probably a better fit on [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/), no?

Comment: @Shokhet It might, if there was a chance eggshells actually would start flying when filled with dew. Since there isn't, it's up to us to figure out what Rashi was talking about.

Comment: @DoubleAA Place the opening with the hole on the bottom, the whole shell heats up, expelling steam out the bottom.....

Comment: Also, @DoubleAA, does that Rashi have to mean the eggshell, and not the dew itself in the form of steam?

Comment: http://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/humor/eggs.htm. Although when I went through this a couple of years ago, the conclusion was it was referring to the dew, not the egg, I don't remember why.

Comment: @Shokhet He says היא whereas טל is masculine, I think.

Comment: @DoubleAA IDK, is it?

Comment: @Shokhet כַּאֲשֶׁר יִפֹּל הַטַּל עַל-הָאֲדָמָה ([*Sh'mu'el* II 17:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08b17.htm#12)). However, Rashi may have been referring to שכבת הטל, even though he [omitted the word שכבת](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29). That's feminine.

Comment: Someone on the internet [claims](http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=2998457&whichpage=3&forum_id=771) to have conducted this experiment multiple times, and says that one time the egg rose a few centimeters.

Comment: Perhaps a related Rashi: [*M'nachos* 69b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=69b&format=text), s.v. שירדו בעבים (*Tosafos*, s.v. חיטין שירדו בעבים, explain that phenomenon as occurring via a miracle).

Comment: [Related](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123570/53027)

Comment: I will refrain from commenting on this on Physics.SE, but will suggest here that the location on earth, and the time-of-year may be important factors — if this is more than a midrash-like story.

Comment: @NewAlexandria I had the same idea....maybe, [maybe not](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123570/flying-eggshells#comment254526_123579)

Comment: [Other cultures had legends of eggs standing on-end (or uprighting themselves) on the Vernal Equinox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_balancing).  Perhaps there was a lore known to ancient sages, and what was taught via the mana allowed a largely-unknown phenomenon to be demonstrated.

Comment: I have added references to the volume of the egg and the mass of the shell to the article at http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123570/flying-eggshells/123579#123579 in the hope that an egg might be found for which the physics will allow the egg to levitate.

Comment: discussed here http://en.wiki.admicos.cf/wiki/Talk:Hot_air_balloon#Flying_eggs

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would assume that the concept here would be kinda like a hot air balloon. However, I do know someone who tried, but it didn't work. (that doesn't really mean much, because there are so many things Rashi didn't describe exactly how to do, it should be very easy to go wrong.)